# embedded react app(chat widget) not showing in other react app or html file

Tags: reactjs, embedding

I have a React application with a live chat widget embedded in
embeddedEntryPoint.js. When I directly access the link
`http://localhost:3001/src/embeddedEntryPoint.js` in the browser, the chat
widget shows up in the corner as expected. However, my goal is to include this
live chat widget in another React app. When I include the script in the HTML
file of the second React app, the chat widget doesn't appear:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Meta tags and other head content -->
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript>You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.</noscript>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <script src="http://localhost:3001/src/embeddedEntryPoint.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I've also attempted to include the script in a normal HTML file, but the
widget still doesn't display. The embeddedEntryPoint.js file contains the
necessary React rendering logic using ReactDOM.createRoot and the Provider from
Redux to render the chat widget. Here's a simplified version of the mounting
logic:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store from "./store";
const mountApp = () => {
  const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body);
  root.render(
    <Provider store="{store}">
      <App />
    </Provider>,
  );
};
mountApp();
```

I'm seeking guidance on why the chat widget isn't displaying
when included in the HTML of another React app or even in a standalone HTML
file. Any insights or suggestions on how to properly include and render this
chat widget within a different React environment would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you for your help!

Comment: Try using iframes